# How is a char array maximum size in C determined?

Tags: arrays, c, stack, strtok, libc

Learning C and checking the reference from the [GNU reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Arrays). I don't understand how is the maximum size that can be allocated to a char array defined in an exact way. In my test program when the allocated size for a string array is "small" it works fine but when it is "large" the program start behaving erratically. **The compiler throws no errors when it gets compiled** but during runtime, it is affecting the correctness of my program that uses `strtok()`, missing some valid tokens in the result.

Taking as input (considering 5 an arbitrary "small" array size):

```
>> 5 
>> 19 65 41 65 56
```

The sum output is 246 so it works well

But taking as input (considering 53 an arbitrary "large" array size):

```
>> 53
>> 19 65 41 65 56 74 76 71 29 44 45 9 66 37 59 6 71 8 30 29 41 31 96 86 11 14 29 24 17 65 88 23 21 49 31 96 72 39 83 96 96 63 44 72 85 38 5 11 70 36 90 49 76
```

The sum output is 2247 which is wrong (correct is 2647). This incorrectness holds for any "large" number of `array_size`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
  /*Array size is the amount of integers that will be introduced later. E.g: 5 (introducting 5 integers next) -> 3 4 5 6 7*/
  /*The numbers are 1 <= n <= 1000 */
  int array_size;  
  scanf("%d", &array_size);
  printf("The array size you introduced is %d\n", array_size);  

  /* Given that the integers introduced can have at most 4 digits and they are separated by a whitespace character, array_size*5 is allocated */
  char sentence[array_size * 5];
  scanf("\n");
  scanf("%[^\n]%*c", sentence);

  char delimiter = ' ';
  char *token;
  token = strtok(sentence, &delimiter);
  int sumResult; 
  printf("The token %d is %s\n", 1, token);   
                     
  while (token != NULL) {                
    sumResult = sumResult + atoi(token);
    token = strtok(NULL, &delimiter);
    printf("The token is %s\n", token);
  }
  
  printf("%d\n", sumResult);
}
```

Comment: That doesn't solve it :(

Comment: @varinme This statement printf("The token is %s\n", token); can invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks, @VladfromMoscow can you point me to why is that? Do you mean I should dereference "token"?

Comment: @varinme You need to execute this statement only if token is not a null pointer.

Comment: @varinme see my answer - I have corrected your errors and it works fine

Comment: Thanks @0___________  ! That's amazing thank you very much for such a detailed explanation <3

Comment: Although it does not address the question posed, consider reading the data one number at a time instead of a whole line at a time.  That could greatly simplify your program, and it would sidestep the specific issue you're having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are (at least) three errors in the program:

`int sumResult;` leaves `sumResult` uninitialized. It must be initialized to zero, as with `int sumResult = 0;`.

`strtok(sentence, &delimiter)` passes the address of a single character to `strtok`. For the second parameter, `strtok` expects a pointer to the first character of a string, meaning a sequence of characters terminating by a null character. Change the definition of `delimeter` to `char delimiter[] = " ";` and change both `strtok` calls to `strtok(sentence, delimiter);`.

`printf("The token is %s\n", token);` is executed once when `token` is a null pointer. For `%s`, `printf` should be passed a pointer to the first character of a string, not a null pointer. This can be remedied by moving this `printf` to be the first line in the `while` loop and deleting the prior `printf("The token %d is %s\n", 1, token);`.

Comment: Thanks for such a comprehensive explanation! I will be studying this in-depth!

Comment: Going over this again, I messed up with the second argument of strtok() and now I understand why. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
int sumResult;
```

When `sumResult` is not initialized, it does not have a determined value. In the language of the C standard, is value is *indeterminate*, meaning that the program may behave as if `sumResult` has no fixed value at all; it may appear to have different values at different times. Further, in this program, using it without it being initialized results in the entire behavior of the program not being defined by the C standard.

```
int sumResult = 0;
```

In the C language object (variables) have different storage durations.

1. Variables defined in the function scope have *automatic* storage duration and are not automatically initialized.
2. Variables defined outside of any function (file scope) and variables defined in functions but declared as `static` have *static* storage duration and **are** automatically initialized (to zero or equivalent for their type) on program startup.

You can do it much easier:

```
int main(void)
{
/*Array size is the amount of integers that will be introduced later. E.g: 5 (introducting 5 integers next) -> 3 4 5 6 7*/
/*The numbers are 1 <= n <= 1000 */
    size_t array_size;  
    if(scanf("%zu",&array_size) != 1) {/* error handling */}
    printf("The array size you introduced is %zu\n", array_size);  
    int array[array_size];

    /* Given that the integers introduced can have at most 4 digits and they are separated by a whitespace character, array_size*5 is allocated */
    int sumResult = 0; 

    for(size_t num = 0; num < array_size; num++)
    {
        if(scanf("%d", array + num) != 1 ) {/* error handling */; break;}
        sumResult += array[num];
    }
    printf("%d\n", sumResult);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/zoWz1cjc7

Your code "repaired"

```
int main(){
  /*Array size is the amount of integers that will be introduced later. E.g: 5 (introducting 5 integers next) -> 3 4 5 6 7*/
  /*The numbers are 1 <= n <= 1000 */
  int array_size;  
  scanf("%d", &array_size);
  printf("The array size you introduced is %d\n", array_size);  

  /* Given that the integers introduced can have at most 4 digits and they are separated by a whitespace character, array_size*5 is allocated */
  char sentence[array_size * 5];
  scanf("\n");
  scanf("%[^\n]%*c", sentence);

  char delimiter[] = " ";
  char *token;
  token = strtok(sentence, delimiter);
  int sumResult = 0; 
  printf("The token %d is %s\n", atoi(token), token);   
                     
  while (token != NULL) {                
    sumResult = sumResult + atoi(token);
    printf("The token is %s %d\n", token, atoi(token));
    token = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
  }
  
  printf("%d\n", sumResult);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/1qj3acn55

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't solve it. It has to do with the size of the array not with the initialization of sumArray. It works consistently well for small sizes but breaks when the amount of numbers is large.

Comment: @varinme see more simple code

Comment: @varinme: When the value stored in an object is not controlled, because the program has not initialized it, it can be affected by other things, such as the size of some array that is created. So you cannot conclude merely from experiments showing that the program “works consistently well” for small sizes but not for large sizes means the problem is not that `sumResult` is not initialized.

Comment: Thanks for the insight @EricPostpischil . I did edit the code and initialized sumArray to zero but the behavior is still the same that's why I previously commented that :confused

Comment: @varinme you do not need strtok to read values.